# Can Hystrix be used without Eureka/ Ribbon or other Netflix OSS modules

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka, hystrix, turbine

We have an infrastructure with our own API gateway, service discovery and load balancing. However for resiliency purposes I need to use Hystrix.

1. With spring cloud netflix, can Hystrix (i.e. The circuit breaker annotation) be used **without** Eureka/ Ribbon or other Netflix OSS modules?
2. Are there any dependency to Eureka/ Ribbon / Zuul for circuit breaker dashboard (i.e. turbine and stream aggregator) ?
3. Can circuit breaker annotation be used in a non spring-boot application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Cloud Hystrix can be used without ribbon or eureka, just use `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix`. The hystrix dashboard can be used by directly going to each instances `hystrix.stream` one at a time. Hystrix can be used without spring boot if you use the Netflix package directly without using Spring Cloud.

Comment: That means the stream aggregator (push mode) needs Eureka running?

Comment: Vanilla turbine is not push, it's pull. Spring Cloud Netflix Turbine is push. They both require eureka.

Comment: I found that hystrix dashboard is available for cloud foundry without eureka. http://cosmos-dev.cfapps.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: I found that hystrix dashboard is available for cloud foundry without eureka. @spencergibb can you please explain how that is possible - whether the same approach as in CF be used in my infrastructures as well?

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes
2. No idea, run it and see if it pulls the dependencies.
3. Yes if it's used with spring and you declare all the necessary beans that spring boot with otherwise instantiate. Otherwise no (more in the [FAQ - Can annotations be used?](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/FAQ#user-content-can-annotations-be-used)

I would suggest you to google a bit before posting questions like this, as it's on the edge of asking for a tool, which is not a suitable question for SO.